# How to add a new whosonfirst place to an existing pelias database?

Tags: pelias

I created a pelias database using pelias/whosonfirst with configuring imports.whosonfirst.importPlace with Turkeys wof id at pelias.json file. Now I want to add United Kingdom too but i don't want to download the entire database(27 GB). Is it possible too extract this data from already installed whosonfirst-data-latest.db?

I used *pelias download wof* command after installing pelias/docker from github. It installed the database to the $DATA_DIR specified in .env file with *imports.whosonfirst.importPlace: [turkey_wof_id]* configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whosonfirst importer will reuse the existing `whosonfirst-data-latest.db` file if there has not been an updated version released since you last downloaded the data.

At this time (August 2019), the file was last updated in May, so it will automatically be reused in your case.

You can learn more in the (recently updated) [downloader documentation](https://github.com/pelias/whosonfirst/#downloading-the-data)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to directly use the installed database instead of checking the latest version from the internet. Btw, I get an 404 error from the link you have provided.

Comment: Oops thanks, link is fixed.

Avoiding the version check [may be supported in the future](https://github.com/pelias/whosonfirst/issues/340)